# isset multiple check boxes in php from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i am populating a form from mysql. code is. .

```
task.php

<div data-role="content">
               <h2> Please select cars </h2>
<form method="post" action="cars.php">
            <?php 
            $carq = "select * from cars";
            $executecars = mysql_query($carq);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($executecars)){
                $cname = $row['name'];  
                ?>

               <label for="<?php echo $cname; ?>"><?php echo $cname; ?></label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="car" id="<?php echo $cname; ?>" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/>

            <?php }     

            ?>
           <input type="submit" name="submitcars" id="submitcars" value="View Details"/>
           </form>
         </div>
```

now in cars.php i want to make a query to display the details of car selected,

```
<div data-role="content">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['submitcars'])){

                echo $_POST[$cname];?????????????


                }
        ?>

        </div>
```

now how to process the form here in cars.php ?

thanks

Comment: Form tag should be outside the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make car attribute array::

```
<input type="checkbox" name="car[]" id="<?php echo $cname; ?>" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/>
```

and get them on next page with

```
if(isset($_POST['submitcars'])){
   foreach($_POST['car'] as $car){
       // do something with $car
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="cars.php">
<?php 
            $carq = "select * from cars";
            $executecars = mysql_query($carq);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($executecars)){
                $cname = $row['name'];  
                ?>

               <label for="<?php echo $cname; ?>"><?php echo $cname; ?></label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="car[]" id="<?php echo $cname; ?>" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/>

            <?php }     

            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me preface this by saying that you shouldn't be using the mysql functions. They're depreciated and no longer recommended.

On task.php, your opening form tag was being printed inside your loop. Secondly, you should probably use an array of checkboxes using [].

```
     <div data-role="content">
        <h2> Please select cars </h2>
        <form method="post" action="cars.php">
        <?php 
        $carq = "select * from cars";
        $executecars = mysql_query($carq);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($executecars)){
            $cname = $row['name'];  
            ?>

           <label for="<?php echo $cname; ?>"><?php echo $cname; ?></label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" id="<?php echo $cname; ?>" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/>

        <?php }  ?>
       <input type="submit" name="submitcars" id="submitcars" value="View Details"/>
       </form>
    </div>
```

Then, on cars.php:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submitcars'])){

            if(isset($_POST['cars'] && count($_POST['cars']) > 0){

                 foreach($_POST['cars'] as $key => $car){

                     echo $car . '<br /'>;

                 }                    

            }
            else{
                echo 'No cars found!';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```